# CAS numbers for salts of molecules

Tags: identification

Often times Pharma molecules come as different salts where the Cation changes. Do these have typically the same or different CAS numbers?

e.g. Take Glucosamine Hydrochloride. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucosamine

It is available as as both the Na and K salt. But I cannot seem to find if they all have different CAS numbers.

What I have now is: 3416-24-8

Further complication seems that there is a Glucosamine Hydrochloride as well as a Sulfate. The wikipedia page describes both but I cannot see different CAS numbers. The sulfate itself seems available as either a Sodium or Potassium salt.

Any thoughts?

Comment: They are different compounds; why would they have the same CAS number?

Comment: @IvanNeretin: Makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every different compound has a different CAS number, even if they are enanthiomers when isolated and published (their racemic mixture has another CAS number). No exception! See following examples:

L-(−)-Glyceraldehyde: CAS Number [497-09-6].

D-(+)-Glyceraldehyde: CAS Number [453-17-8].

DL-(+/-)-Glyceraldehyde: CAS Number [56-82-6].

For your question, I found the CAS Number of D-(+)-glucosamine hydrochloride, which is [66-84-2]. The CAS Number [3416-24-8] is for glucosamine (free base).

The CAS Number of D-glucosamine sulfate is [14999-43-0]. Each molecule contains two molecules of glucosamines and one molecule of $\ce{H2SO4}$, the two acedic hydrogens on each of amine groups. Its molecular formula is $\ce{[C6H14NO5]2.SO4}$, giving the formula weight: $\pu{456.42 g/mol}$.

The CAS Number of D-glucosamine sulfate potassium chloride is [216699-44-4]. Each molecule contains two molecules of glucosamines, one molecule of $\ce{H2SO4}$, and two molecules of $\ce{KCl}$. Its molecular formula is $\ce{[C6H14NO5]2.SO4.2KCl}$, giving the formula weight: $\pu{605.52 g/mol}$. However, [NIH website](https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/rn/1296149-08-0) listed [1296149-08-0] as the CAS Number of glucosamine sulfate Potassium chloride, which must be issued a fairly recent time. [Spectrum Chemical Co.](https://www.spectrumchemical.com/OA_HTML/chemical-cas_Glucosamine-Sulfate-Potassium-Chloride-USP_1296149-08-0.jsp?pCasName=Glucosamine-Sulfate-Potassium-Chloride-USP) sells the compound as a dietary supplement under the same CAS number.